# Is there an SQL function to add total units of products surfacing in data multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am cutting down some data to make it easier to read, it was entered by every transaction, however I need to have just one row per product code instead of multiple (sums, of units sold and total pounds). How can I do this so I do not have 600,000 rows and only 2,500 products codes.

```
select [master code], [product code], [units sold]
  , [product weight] * [units sold] as 'Total Lbs per Product'
from [dbo].[sales_data_outgoing_master]
where [ship year] = 2019
order by [family code]
```

I am getting an answer like the top table in the photo, and would like a table like the lower. Is there code to do this in SQL?

[image: ME tables depicting issue]

Comment: I only see one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
select [master code], [product code], SUM([units sold]) as [units sold]
    , SUM([product weight] * [units sold]) as 'Total Lbs per Product' 
    , [family code]
from [dbo].[sales_data_outgoing_master]
where [ship year] = 2019
GROUP BY [master code], [product code], [family code]
order by [family code]
```